# jquery addclass in nested <td>

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, conditional-formatting

I am trying to do conditional formatting in a SharePoint list using jquery. The issue I'm having is SharePoint adds a bunch of junk when placing code within a SharePoint Page. I'm trying to conditionally highlight certain cells with certain text in a table. Red = red background, green= green background.

Problem I'm having with the way I coded is, due the fact that my table is wrapped in another table ( I have no control over this) and I'm looking for text with in a td, the parent td gets styled also. I just want to style the specific td with the text in it.

I have a codepen showing what I've done: http://codepen.io/Gregc72/pen/NdmoXj

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
<table>    
<tr><td>Test 1</td><td>Red</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test 2</td><td>Green</td></tr>    
</table>
</tr></td><table>
```

**CSS**

```
.greenBg {
    background: green;
}
.redBg {
    background: red;
}
```

**Script**

```
$("td:contains('Green')").addClass('greenBg');
$("td:contains('Red')").addClass('redBg');
```

I don't know if I can format my css selector differently to accomplish this or if I have to use some sort of looping function. I'm sure the answer is very simple and I'm just overlooking it.

Comment: is a fixed style? or just style when the user do certain actions

Comment: It's a fixed style. Basically, a User will select in a form Red or Yellow and instead of the words red or yellow showing up I want the table cell to be that color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a good idea to use `filter()` function

[**PEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNEowy)

```
$("td").filter(
     function (index) { return $(this).text() == "Red"; }
).addClass("redBg");

$("td").filter(
     function (index) { return $(this).text() == "Green"; }
).addClass("greenBg");
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is your fix structure then try this:

```
$("table tr td table tr td:contains('Green')").addClass('greenBg');
$("table tr td table tr td:contains('Red')").addClass('redBg');
```

Comment: It's just an example. The structure is much more complicated. I was trying to simplify it a bit to only include what i'm looking to do. SharePoint does annoying stuff with injected code that makes life difficult. Also, the text could be in multiple columns. I think your suggestion would work if it was in the same column every time but if I have 20 columns that would get messy.